# Embed SVGs in JSX at build time?

Tags: reactjs, svg, create-react-app

I'm relatively new to React, using create-react-app to build simple prototypes. I'd like to be able to export SVGs from Sketch or a similar design tool and use them in my React app, embedded directly in the JSX since that allows styling via CSS.

This is relatively straightforward with a little effort: copy the exported SVG code out of the original .svg file, tweak how the xmlns attributes are named, done.

But if I have a lot of images and am iterating on them frequently, that becomes incredibly high-effort. I'd like a way to take a directory of SVGs at build time and basically concatenate them into a single .js file, e.g.,

```
const icons = {
    first: <svg>...contents of first svg file...</svg>,
    second <svg>...contents of second file...</svg>,
    ...
}
```

This is relatively trivial to do via shell script or something, but it would be great to integrate into the build process. How would I go about doing something like this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

As of create-react-app version 2, you can import svg files directly as React components. As you're just starting with development and have probably installed create-react-app package recently and won't suffer any possible side-effects from updating to new version of create-react-app, just edit the **react-scripts** entry in package.json to say `"react-scripts": "^2.0.3"` and run `npm install` or `yarn install`.

Then you'll be able to do this:

```js
import { ReactComponent as Logo } from './logo.svg';

const App = () => (
    <div>
        <Logo />
    </div>
);
```

[Source: create-react-app Github page readme](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files#adding-svgs)

Comment: Nice! This appears to solve much of my problem. However, I'm passing the SVG to a Blueprint component that seems to expect an SVG tag (as defined in JSX). How best to achieve that?